# tkinterでFrameを入れ子構造にしたい

Tags: python, tkinter

pythonのtkinterの練習でFrameを入れ子構造にする練習をしていたのですが、以下のコードだと小さなウィンドウが出現するばかりで、失敗してしまいます。どうすれば成功するでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import tkinter as Tk

class Frame(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("NEsted Frames")

        f1 = Tk.Frame(self, relief=Tk.RIDGE, bd = 2)
        for text, color in [("A", "magenta"),('B', 'yellow'), ('C', 'SeaGreen'), ('D', 'LightSkyBlue')]:
            l = Tk.Label(f1, text =text, bg = color, font=("Helvetica","16"))
            l.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        f1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)


        f2 =Tk.Frame(self, relief=Tk.RIDGE, bd=2)
        for i, (text, color) \
                        in enumerate([('A', 'magenta'), ('B', 'yellow'), ('C', 'SeaGreen'), ('D', 'LightSkyBlue')]):
                            l =Tk.Label(f2, text=text, bg=color, font=('Helvetica', '16'))
                            l.grid(row = i%2, column=i%2)
        f2.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

placeで配置する場合は親ウィジェットの大きさを指定しておく必要があります。

```
Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=500, height=500)
```

Comment: できました！ありがとうございました。